# VBA throws an error suggesting i need a constant. I define it a few lines prior

Tags: vba, excel

I'm admittedly brand new to VBA. I've searched through similar problems but I don't understand if my problem is identical.

Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
Dim T As Double 'the root being sought
Dim F As Double
Dim dFdT As Double
Dim DeltaT As Double
Const Tol = 0.0000001 'convergence tolerance
Dim Iter As Integer

'Permit a maximum of 10 iterations
n = 10

If R = 0 Then

    For Iter = 1 To n

        F = Xr - Vo * T
        dFdT = -Vo
        DeltaT = F / dFdT
        If Abs(DeltaT) < Tol Then GoTo Solution
        T = T - DeltaT

    Next Iter

    MsgBox "No root found", vbExclamation, "PolyRoot result"
```

I get the following error when I try to access this formula:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYLTK.png

> Compile error, constant expression required"

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I needed a colon after Then in "Then GoTo Solution"

Using "Then: Goto Solution" fixed my problem. Sorry for not providing enough details. I assumed this would be diagnosable from the information provided.

Comment: Your code does not compile on my machine, various symbols are undefined such as `Xr` and `Vo`. Please provide a version of your code that uses `Option Explicit` and please also provide initial values for `T`, `F`, `dFdT`, and `DeltaT`.

Comment: get the const out of the fuction / procedure